# How to "continue" a for loop from a callback function with pynput and winsound?

Tags: python, playback

I need to have my program play wav files from a directory and skip to the next one if the user presses F9. I have found I need to set the winsound to Async mode to get it to skip to the next file while the previous file is still playing, but at the same time i need to run a background process like time.sleep(5) or else the program will exit immediately.

I have a for loop to run through the wav files, but I can't directly call continue from the on_press() function so I tried using a conditional global variable to sleep or not sleep. Thus, I can stop the current playing wav file with PlaySound(None, winsound.Purge) but I can't continue to the next iteration of the for loop or get my time.sleep(5) to conditionally run - it will always run and I will always have to wait those 5 seconds to start the next iteration. Is there a problem with the way I'm using the callback or should I use a different input lib or something?

```
from pynput import keyboard
import winsound
import os

mySkip = 0
currentIdx = 0

def clamp(n, minn, maxn):
    return max(min(maxn, n), minn)

def on_press(key):
    global mySkip
    global currentIdx
    if key == keyboard.Key.f9:
        winsound.Beep(5500, 200)
        mySkip = 1

        currentIdx = clamp(currentIdx + 1, 0, 3)
        winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

WAVDir = "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/projectName/WAV"
wavList = os.listdir(WAVDir) #have 4 files in here, "test0.wav" to "test4.wav"

for idx, i in enumerate(wavList):
    soundPath = WAVDir + "/test" + str(currentIdx) + ".wav"

    print(soundPath)
    winsound.PlaySound(soundPath, winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    if mySkip == 0:
        time.sleep(5)

    currentIdx += 1
    mySkip = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with using polling - which is never my favorite thing to do, but `winsound` is notoriously uncooperative when it comes to threading, and I believe that threading is the way to go here:

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path
    from threading import Event, Thread
    from pynput import keyboard
    from collections import namedtuple
    import wave

    skip_sound = Event()

    def play_sound_thread(path, max_duration_seconds):
        from winsound import PlaySound, SND_ASYNC
        PlaySound(path, SND_ASYNC)
        elapsed_seconds = 0
        poll_interval = 1 / 8
        while not skip_sound.is_set() and elapsed_seconds < max_duration_seconds:
            skip_sound.wait(poll_interval)
            elapsed_seconds += poll_interval

    def on_press(key):
        if key is keyboard.Key.f9:
            nonlocal skip_sound
            skip_sound.set()

    Wave = namedtuple("Wave", ["path", "file_name", "duration_seconds"])

    waves = []

    wav_dir = Path("./wavs")

    for wav_path in wav_dir.glob("*.wav"):
        wav_path_as_str = str(wav_path)
        file_name = wav_path.name
        with wave.open(wav_path_as_str, "rb") as wave_read:
            sample_rate = wave_read.getframerate()
            number_of_samples = wave_read.getnframes()
        duration_seconds = number_of_samples / sample_rate

        wav = Wave(
            path=wav_path_as_str,
            file_name=file_name,
            duration_seconds=duration_seconds
        )

        waves.append(wav)

    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
    listener.start()

    for wav in waves:
        print(f"Playing {wav.file_name}")

        thread = Thread(
            target=play_sound_thread,
            args=(wav.path, wav.duration_seconds),
            daemon=True
        )
        thread.start()
        thread.join()

        if skip_sound.is_set():
            print(f"Skipping {wav.file_name}")
            skip_sound.clear()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

How it works:

Every time a sound needs to be played, a new thread is spawned and the `winsound.PlaySound` stuff is done in the thread. `PlaySound` receives the `SND_ASYNC` argument, so that the sound is played asynchronously, and this operation by itself does not block execution in the thread. The thread's execution is then blocked, however, by a loop, which terminates when either a certain amount of time has elapsed (the sound has had enough time to finish playing) or when the `skip_sound` event is set.

The `on_press` callback sets the `skip_sound` event when the f9 key is pressed.

I've created a `namedtuple` called `Wave`, which is just meant to act like a simple data bucket. All the relevant information we need for any single wave file is contained in one of these.

The main for-loop (the second one, the first one just compiles a list of `Wave` objects), we iterate through our `Wave` objects. We then spawn a new thread for the current `Wave` object. We then start the thread to start playing the sound, and `thread.join` it so that the main thread waits for this sub-thread to finish - basically blocking until the sub-thread is finished. When the `on_press` callback is triggered, it terminates the sub-thread prematurely, and as a result the `join` operation will no longer be blocking, allowing us to reset our `skip_sound` event if necessary and move on to the next iteration.

Things I like about this solution:

- It works

Things I don't like about this solution:

- Like I said, the `play_sound_thread` function plays the sound
  asynchronously, and then polls until either the `skip_sound` event is
  triggered, or a certain amount of time has elapsed. Polling is gross. I just sort of arbitrarily decided to poll in 1/8th of a second intervals.
- In order to determine the maximum duration for which to poll, you
  need to open the wave file, parse it, and divide the number of
  samples by the sample rate. It feels dirty to basically open the same
  file twice - once in `wave.open`, and again in `winsound.PlaySound`.